# Ant copy task : Copying all only src folder (including subdirectories ) under each Project to single directory

Tags: java, ant, build

I have following directory structure:

```
RootFolder
    |build.xml
    |Project 1
        |src
        |resources
    |Project 2
        |src
        |resources      
    |Project 3
        |src        
        |resources
```

i would like to Copy  all only src folder (including subdirectories ) under each Project to single directory

**This what i have tried**

```
<target name="prep_emma" >  
    <copy todir="${dest.dir}/src" verbose="true"  >
         <fileset dir="${RootFolder}">          
             <include name="**/JavaSource/com/**/*.java"/>
         </fileset>
    </copy> 
</target>
```

But this creates the entire folder structure at the destination

```
dest.dir
    |Project 1
        |src        
    |Project 2
        |src        
    |Project 3
        |src
```

**but I want**

```
dest.dir    
    |src
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [file mapper](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html), cutdirsmapper should be sufficient, f.e. :

```
<copy todir="${dest.dir}/src" verbose="true"  >
 <fileset dir="${RootFolder}">          
  <include name="**/JavaSource/com/**/*.java"/>
 </fileset>
 <cutdirsmapper dirs="1"/>
</copy>
```

means the leading Project x is stripped.

> cutdirsmapper (since Ant 1.8.2)
>
> This mapper strips a configured number of leading directories from the
>   source file name.